# Ruby - Error accessing instance variables

Tags: arrays, ruby, each, instance-variables

I'm learning Ruby, and I'm having a problem while making a program.

I have a class "LineAnalyzer" that has 4 parameters (2 provided and 2 calculated). Both calculated params are: @high_wf_count (integer) and @high_wf_words (array).
Then, I have this one:

```
class Solution < LineAnalyzer
    attr_reader :analyzers, 
                :highest_count_across_lines, 
                :highest_count_words_across_lines

    def initialize
        @analyzers = [] 
    end

    def analyze_file
        File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
            @analyzers << LineAnalyzer.new(line.chomp,@analyzers.length+1)
        end 
    end

    def calculate_line_with_highest_frequency
        @highest_count_words_across_lines = []
        @highest_count_across_lines = @analyzers.max_by do 
            |a| a.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_count)
        end .instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_count)

        @highest_count_words_across_lines << @analyzers.each do
            |a| a.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_count) == @highest_count_across_lines
        end .instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_words)
    end    
end
```

The problem is that I cannot append the array `@highest_wf_count` to `@highest_count_words_across_lines` in the way I've done (it returns `nil`). But, I've previously taken the integer `@highest_wf_count` in the same way perfectly.

Can anyone tell me where's the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem is in this bit of code:

```
@highest_count_words_across_lines << @analyzers.each do
    |a| a.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_count) == @highest_count_across_lines
end .instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_words)
```

Preferably formatted as:

```
@highest_count_words_across_lines << @analyzers.each do |analyzer|
  analyzer.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_count) == @highest_count_across_lines
end.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_words)
```

The problem here is that you are calling `.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_words)` on the result of the `:each` method.

A few lines above, you are doing something similar, where you call `.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_count)` on the result of the `:max_by` method, and it is working.

The difference between `:max_by` and `:each` is that `:max_by` returns a single analyzer, whereas `:each` returns the array of `@analyzers` over which it is iterating.

When you call `:instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_words)` on that array, it's returning `nil` because an array will not have an instance variable named `:@highest_wf_words`

That is where your problem exists.

### Sidenote:

It is generally not good practice to ever use `:instance_variable_get`. I would recommend adding to your analyzer class `attr_reader :highest_wf_words, :highest_wf_count`

Then, instead of calling `analyzer.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_words)`, you can just call `analyzer.highest_wf_words`

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didn't notice the difference between those functions.
And, is there any way of taking all the values :highest_wf_word in :analyzer so that its :highest_wf_count is maximum in a single line? Or any function that fits better for this need. Thanks again!

Comment: You might want to look into the `:select` method on arrays: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select that will allow you to filter `@analyzers` by only the ones with the highest_count_across_lines. If you are using `:select`, it also returns an array, and you'll want to use `+=` instead of `<<`, because you'll want to add the arrays together, rather than put one inside of the other.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot going on here and most of the code results from going against the grain when writing Ruby. Using `instance_variable_get` should be an absolute last resort. It's considered highly rude to just reach into an object and pull out a variable. It creates ugly and undesirable inter-dependencies. If that other object wanted to give you that value it would have a method to access it.

The way I see it what you're trying to do boils down to something like this:

```
def highest_frequency
  @analyzers.map do |a|
    a.highest_wf_count
  end.sort.last
end
```

Let `Analyzer` implement `highest_wf_count` as a method, even if it's just an `attr_reader`. This gives you the flexibility to change how and when that value is computed. Maybe you don't need to do it when the object is initialized. Maybe it's done in another thread, or it's evaluated lazily.

Whenever possible try and structure your code as a series of *straight-forward transformations*. Try not to create convoluted, branching, ugly comparisons. Lean on Enumerable whenever possible, it's usually got a method that does exactly what you want, or two that in conjunction do the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is way more complex than it needs to be (or should be).

Why does `Solution` subclass `LineAnalyzer`?  And why are you using `instance_variable_get`?  You should define getter methods using `attr_reader` on the LineAnalyzer class so you can call methods instead of using `instance_variable_get`, which is a brute force approach that should only be used as a last resort.

I think you should fix this before proceeding.

When you have instance methods created with attr_reader, calculating the max becomes very simple:

```
highest_count_across_lines = @analyzers.map(&:highest_wf_count).max
```

I think your error probably is caused by these lines:

```
 @highest_count_words_across_lines << @analyzers.each do
            |a| a.instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_count) == @highest_count_across_lines
        end .instance_variable_get(:@highest_wf_words)
```

I suggest simplifying this code, and the error will probably present itself to you. Did you really mean to append the value returned by `each` to @highest_count_words_across_lines?  This will be an Array of analyzers. The Array class, of course, does not have a variable named `:@highest_wf_words`.

Again, I think you really need to simplify this code.